# Tracing recursive calls in OOP

Tags: scala, oop, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I am somewhat comfortable with tracing/understanding recursive calls in functional languages like Javascript, Haskell, recently I am taking course in Scala and at present the course is relying heavily on recursion.

Here is the simple example:

```
abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet
}

class Empty extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet = other
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
   if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
   else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
   else this

  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet =
   ((left union right) union other)incl(elem)
}
```

Although intuitively recursion seems understandable but I am having hard time expanding the general case whereas the `base case` feels perfectly fine.

```
((left union right) union other)incl(elem)
```

mainly because of the left reference context which are not there in the normal functional languages. How can I make myself comfortable while working and understanding with these recursive calls?

**Update**

Based on the answers I think below would be the sequence of calls to expand the recursion tree.

1. `incl(union(union(left, right), other), elem)`
2. `incl(union(incl(union(union(left, right), other), elem), other), elem)`

But I think it would become too hairy very soon, is there any pictorial alternative or modal to understand this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*because of the left reference context which are not there in the normal functional languages.*"? What's a "normal" functional language, and how would the function look there?

Comment: @Bergi I mean normally I do `function foo(largerInstance) -> function foo(smallerInstance) .... function foo(baseCase)` i.e. my function calls depends only on arguments but here I see the function depends on the object on which function is called.

Comment: Consider an object on which function is called as an implicit argument which always exist (not always used though, especially in Scala). Like `incl(union(union(left, right), other), elem)`. Only all functions are polymorphic on their first argument.

Comment: @CodeYogi Consider the object as the first argument, and the properties being implicitly destructured/pattern-matched etc.

Comment: @VictorMoroz great but don't you think expanding this function would be a painful task, also which notation you feel more helpful this one or the object reference one while thinking of the recursive algorithm?

Comment: @Bergi it would really help if you could provide some simple example on tree like data structure because this concept is fairly new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Union is a tricky method to understand here, it's true. When I first saw it, it seemed peculiar that it worked at all, seeing as it seems to be doing very little. It does help to draw out two small trees and trace through it to see how the whole thing works, but essentially, it's no different than any other recursion. Most of the work is done by `incl`, which is actually adding every element to the int set, one at a time. All union does is recursively break down the problem over and over again, until you get to an empty int set. Then one by one incl method adds every element back into the set, building it up to a set that includes all the elements in the original int set and the other int set.

Odersky's course is great by the way. Finished it myself a few months ago.